# change the rows to increment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table containing multiple columns. I am using the SQL Server 2008.  I need to change the value of one of the rows in the table increment for each raw based on a value I get from another table.

For example if my table items are:

```
row1    row2     row3   
kk       aa       1
bb       ss       2
```

I need to read a value from another table for example: MAX(Table_2.row9)=5 and then modify the table to be:

```
row1    row2     row3   
kk       aa       6
bb       ss       7
```

I am aware of IDENTITY column my idea was to have the column as IDENTITY and then have a code sort of like:

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE> IDENTITY = (select MAX(F27)+1 FROM <TABLE2>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reseed IDENTITY value it is not going to affect already existing rows but only count for newly inserted. And if you column is identity you will not be able to update it.

If all you need is to simply update values, then you can keep it simple:

```
DECLARE @m INT
SELECT @m = MAX(F27)+1 FROM Table2

UPDATE Table1
SET Row3 = Row3 + @m
```

**EDIT - after additional info:**
If  you need that column to become identity after updating it - you'll have to do some workaround:

1. Create a new table that's same except for having an identity property.
2. Set identity insert ON for new table
3. Copy data from existing table to new table, adjusting for wanted ID (already updated in old table)
4. Set identity insert OFF for new table
5. DROP existing table (or for safety rename it to TableName_OLD for now)
6. Rename new table to old name

OR

Just use Management Studio's Table Designer to change the IDENTITY property of column to Yes. It will do all the above steps for you in the background.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, Yes that's sort of the thing, however the point is that if I don't make the column Identity then at the entry of the rows that column will be null, and if it's Identity then I can't change the value

Comment: @kou In that case you need to do some workaround. I'll edit the answer to explain.

Comment: ok thanks, The script needs to be scheduled to be executed automatically. So I am going with the first solution.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for an `UPDATE` statement:

```
update table1 
set row3 = row3 + (select max(f27) from table2);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e1ad/1)

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, Yes that's sort of the thing, however the point is that if I don't make the column Identity then at the entry of the rows that column will be null, and if it's Identity then I can't change the value